# What would cause bash to be unable to execute a .jar written and compiled on my own machine?

Tags: java, macos, unix

It worked fine yesterday, and it runs fine with `java -jar ...` however now when I try to run it this is the response I get:

```
-bash: ./Shuffle: cannot execute binary file
```

Here's a snippet of the Makefile:

```
$(JARFILE): $(CLASSES)
    echo Main-class: $(MAINCLASS) > Manifest
    jar cvfm $(JARFILE) Manifest $(JARCLASSES)
    chmod +x $(JARFILE)
    rm Manifest
```

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.8 and have tried reinstalling the update released yesterday Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 5 with no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: For those who may reference this later, I reinstalled OS X (surprisingly easy/convenient) and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that Shuffle is the name of your jar file.

Bash simply does not know how to execute jar files. Jar files are not executable files. They are zip archives, with certain pre-defined file structure inside. Wikipedia provides good explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_file.

To run jar file from bash you may create a bash script. A simple example is:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar Shuffle
```

BTW, since jar files are not executable files, you can remove `chmod +x $(JARFILE)`, from your Makefile.

Comment: On a Mac as on Windows *jar files are executeabel files*!!

Comment: That is not correct. On Windows there is a file association between for jar files with javaw.exe, which is equivalent to the java.exe, but had no console window associated. In result when "start" a jar file it is simply opened with javaw.exe. I assume that on Mac there is similar association.